# asyncio + multiprocessing + unix

Tags: python, unix, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have a pet project with the following logic:

```
import asyncio, multiprocessing

async def sub_main():
    print('Hello from subprocess')

def sub_loop():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(sub_main())

def start():
    multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_loop).start()

start()
```

If you run it, you'll see:

```
Hello from subprocess
```

That is good. But what I have to do is to make `start()` coroutine instead:

```
async def start():
    multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_loop).start()
```

To run it, I have to do something like that:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())
```

Here is the issue: when sub process is created, it gets the whole Python environment cloned, so event loop is already running there:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 7, in sub_loop
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(sub_main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 361, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 326, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is running.')
RuntimeError: Event loop is running.
```

I tried to destroy it on subprocess side with no luck but I think that the correct way is to prevent its sharing with subprocess though. Is it possible somehow?

**UPDATE**:
Here is the full failing code:

```
import asyncio, multiprocessing

import asyncio.unix_events

async def sub_main():
    print('Hello from subprocess')

def sub_loop():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(sub_main())


async def start():
    multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_loop).start()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())
```

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but you may want to consider a design where (a) your multiprocessing stuff is done by a script that can be invoked using eg. `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "the_script.py"], ...)` (b) this script communicates with its parent on eg. `stdout` using a designed protocol (it could be totally simple, eg. single byte control characters to the script and status updates back) and (c) using the [asyncio subprocess API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html).

Comment: (I don't mean you should use `subprocess.Popen` and asyncio's subprocess API at the same time, just that you should write your script so that it *could be* controlled as any language-agnostic subprocess.)

Comment: @detly Thank for the suggestion, but there is a plenty of data which should be inherited by subprocess. If there is a simple solution to avoid the mentioned problem, I'd prefer it rather then rewriting all multiprocessing stuff by hand.

Comment: That's fair enough, it's not a trivial undertaking.

Comment: I think that this is possible since I've found a hack which seems to be working but only on unix platform. `sub_loop` can start with `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop())` which will create a new loop for the subprocess while the parent's one would be (hopefully) garbage collected

Comment: Your code with the `async def start`, and `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())` works fine for me.  Are you sure your issue isn't with some other code you're not showing us?

Comment: @Gerrat Now I am not :) I've added the full code into the end of the question, could you please try it? Are you on Windows?

Comment: @Grief:  Yes, running on Windows (so I had to remove the unix events) .  If your issue is what I think it is though, my answer should work in a linux environment as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you should consider using [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) with a [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) if you plan to run python subprocesses from within the loop. As for your problem, you can use the [event loop policy](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#event-loop-policies-and-the-default-policy) functions to set a new loop:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

async def sub_main():
    print('Hello from subprocess')

def sub_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(sub_main())

async def start(executor):
    await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(executor, sub_loop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start(executor))
```

Comment: Right... I seem to be blind since I've missed this obvious function `asyncio.new_event_loop()`. Thanks! Could you please explain to me what is the profit of `ProcessPoolExecutor` in that case?

Comment: @Grief `run_in_executor` is a coroutine so you can easily join your subprocess using `await` or `asyncio.wait_for` for instance. `ProcessPoolExecutor` also lets you specify a number of workers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the need for creating a new event loop in the created subprocess. This was the key bit I was missing - otherwise was getting a very cryptic `Bad file descriptor` error.

Answer (score 1):

You should always add a check to see how you're running the code (the `if __name__ == '__main__':` part. Your subprocess is running everything in the module a 2nd time, giving you *grief* (couldn't resist).

```
import asyncio, multiprocessing

async def sub_main():
    print('Hello from subprocess')

def sub_loop():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(sub_main())


async def start():
    multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_loop).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())
```

Comment: I guess this is only unix-related since this ends up with the same result, I mean exactly the same exception.

Comment: @Grief:  I'll see if I can replicate your issue in a linux env.

Comment: By the way, they changed that part in the python3 documentation. It was `For an explanation of why (on Windows) the if __name__ == '__main__' part is necessary, see Programming guidelines.` in https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming and now it is just `For an explanation of why the if __name__ == '__main__' part is necessary, see Programming guidelines.` I believe that nothing changed under the hood here and the removal of Windows mention is just a push toward cross platform coding.

Comment: @Grief: ...well, now your question is interesting (to me).  Different results on windows and linux.  I get your exception running on linux.

Comment: I guess I can try-catch exception and do `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop())` if error occurred. At least as a workaround for now. However, I'd prefer something more reliable.